# Apply function to dataframe column element based on value in other column for same row?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'number': ['10', '20' , '30', '40'], 'condition': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B']})

df = 
    number    condition
0    10         A
1    20         B
2    30         A
3    40         B
```

I want to apply a function to each element within the number column, as follows:

```
 df['number'] = df['number'].apply(lambda x: func(x))
```

BUT, even though I apply the function to the number column, I want the function to also make reference to the `condition` column i.e. in pseudo code:

```
func(n):
    #if the value in corresponding condition column is equal to some set of values:
        # do some stuff to n using the value in condition
        # return new value for n
```

For a single number, and an example function I would write:

```
number = 10
condition = A
def func(num, condition):
    if condition == A:
        return num*3
    if condition == B:
        return num*4

func(number,condition) = 15
```

How can I incorporate the same function to my `apply` statement written above? i.e. making reference to the value within the condition column, while acting on the value within the number column?

Note: I have read through the docs on `np.where()`, `pandas.loc()` and `pandas.index()` but I just cannot figure out how to put it into practice.

I am struggling with the syntax for referencing the other column from within the function, as I need access to both the values in the `number` and `condition` column.

As such, my expected output is:

```
df = 
    number    condition
0    30         A
1    80         B
2    90         A
3    160         B
```

UPDATE: The above was far too vague. Please see the following:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Entries':['man','guy','boy','girl'],'Conflict':['Yes','Yes','Yes','No']})


    Entries    Conflict
0    "man"    "Yes"
1    "guy"    "Yes"
2    "boy"    "Yes"
3    "girl"   "No

def funcA(d):
    d = d + 'aaa'
    return d
def funcB(d):
    d = d + 'bbb'
    return d

df1['Entries'] = np.where(df1['Conflict'] == 'Yes', funcA, funcB)

Output:
{'Conflict': ['Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Np'],
 'Entries': array(<function funcB at 0x7f4acbc5a500>, dtype=object)}
```

How can I apply the above np.where statement to take a pandas series as mentioned in the comments, and produce the desired output shown below:

Desired Output:

```
    Entries    Conflict
0    "manaaa"    "Yes"
1    "guyaaa"    "Yes"
2    "boyaaa"    "Yes"
3    "girlbbb"   "No
```

Comment: Firstly your code to create the df has an error, secondly you need `df.apply(lambda row: func(row['number'], row['condition']), axis=1)` this will `apply` row-wise so you can reference the other column. Also one should not resort to `apply` when a vectorised method exists. You could've done `np.where(df['condition'] == 'A', df['num'] * 3, df['num']*4)` but your setup code is passing strings for the number column

Comment: @EdChum Apologies, error checked. I agree - the code is a garbled horrible mess, I'm genuinely surprised it works half the time! Ok, so I could write `df['number'] = np.where(df[condition'] == 'A', functionA, functionB)` and define `functionA` and `functionB` elsewhere (say above that line)?

Comment: You'd need to craft those functions to accept a Series or DataFrame and return either a boolean array or an array that is the same length as the orig df but you've defined this so I can't speculate on non-existent code

Comment: @EdChum the `np.where` solution is fine with very few conditions to check, but would need to be improved in the case of many conditions.

Comment: @not_a_robot my point here is that the OP hasn't fully fleshed their requirements so it's speculative to me, I can only answer with the information presented here

Comment: @EdChum My question was terrible: I have added an update where I have tried to implement your `np.where` suggestion. How would I change this to accept a pandas series as you mention?

Comment: @EdChum In my attempts to make my question applicable in more domains, I instead completely obfuscated it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know about using `pandas.DataFrame.apply`, but you could define a certain `condition:multiplier` key-value mapping (seen in `multiplier` below), and pass that into your function. Then you can use a list comprehension to calculate the new `number` output based on those conditions:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'number': [10, 20 , 30, 40], 'condition': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B']})

multiplier = {'A': 2, 'B': 4}

def func(num, condition, multiplier):
    return num * multiplier[condition]

df['new_number'] = [func(df.loc[idx, 'number'], df.loc[idx, 'condition'], 
                     multiplier) for idx in range(len(df))]
```

Here's the result:

```
df
Out[24]: 
  condition  number  new_number
0         A      10          30
1         B      20          80
2         A      30          90
3         B      40         160
```

There is likely a vectorized, pure-pandas solution that's more "ideal." But this works, too, in a pinch.

Answer (score 16):

As the question was in regard to the **apply** function to a dataframe column for the same row, it seems more accurate to use the pandas `apply` funtion in combination with `lambda`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'number': [10, 20 , 30, 40], 'condition': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B']})

def func(number,condition):
    multiplier = {'A': 2, 'B': 4}
    return number * multiplier[condition]

df['new_number'] = df.apply(lambda x: func(x['number'], x['condition']), axis=1)
```

In this example, `lambda` takes the columns *'number'* and *'condition'* of the dataframe df and applies these columns of the same row to the function *func* with `apply`.

This returns the following result:

```
df
Out[10]: 
 condition  number  new_number
0   A   10  20
1   B   20  80
2   A   30  60
3   B   40  160
```

For the **UPDATE case** its also possible to use the pandas `apply` function:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Entries':['man','guy','boy','girl'],'Conflict':['Yes','Yes','Yes','No']})

def funcA(d):
    d = d + 'aaa'
    return d
def funcB(d):
    d = d + 'bbb'
    return d

df1['Entries'] = df1.apply(lambda x: funcA(x['Entries']) if x['Conflict'] == 'Yes' else funcB(x['Entries']), axis=1)
```

In this example, `lambda` takes the columns *'Entries'* and *'Conflict'* of the dataframe df and applies these columns either to *funcA* or *funcB* of the same row with `apply`. The condition if *funcA* or *funcB* will be applied is done with an `if-else` clause in lambda.

This returns the following result:

```
df
Out[12]:


    Conflict    Entries
0   Yes     manaaa
1   Yes     guyaaa
2   Yes     boyaaa
3   No  girlbbb
```